# Get current browser html content in chrome extension development?

Tags: jquery-plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am working with **chrome extension development and bubble box jquery** plugin.

I need to get *current browser html content* using *chrome extension* so that I will *add html content on It using bubble box jquery plugin.*

Have you any idea ***how to get html content.***

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by html content? Do you know about content scripts? Can you describe in more details what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using jquery so the easy way to get the entire page's html is `$(document).html`

This is pretty basic stuff. Are you stuck trying to figure out how to create your first working chrome extension?